# Yii2 получить параметры предыдущего POST запроса

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет. Есть метод в контроллере с валидацией формы:

```
public function actionAdds() {
        $model = new AddProductForm();

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
            if ($model->validate()) {
                if($model->add()){
                    \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'Товар добавлен.');
                    return $this->redirect('index');
                }
            } else {
                foreach($model->errors as $error) {
                    \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', $error);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->redirect('add');
    }
```

При отрицательном результате идет редирект на `'add'`. Вопрос: каким образом я могу получить данные текущего post запроса после редиректа? Мне необходимо вставить данные в форму, которая проходит данную валидацию. Т.е. мне нужно в виде заполнить форму примерно таким образом:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-title">Название</label>
        <input type="text" value="<?=$previousPost->title?>" name="AddProductForm[title]" class="form-control" id="input-title" placeholder="Кольцо #1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input-description">Описание</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" value="<?=$previousPost->description?>" 
 name="AddProductForm[description]" id="input-description" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
```

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? вставьте в `setFlash` ваш `post` перед редиректом и все будет доступно.

Comment: @Manitikyl только не во Flash а просто в сессию

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо использовать стандартные решения Yii2, такие как ActiveForm. В экшене данные пост-запроса в любом случае загружаются в модель, только в случае безуспешной записи данных в БД надо не редиректить, а отрисовывать вьюшку необходимой формы и передавать в нее модель (в которую были загружены данные). Можно сгенерировать CRUD и посмотреть как это реализовано. Достаточно удобно и практично.